# Java Expression Evaluate

Tags: java, parsing, evaluation, evaluate

I am trying to develop a parser to parse simple logical relationship expressions, which includes "(", ")", ">", "<", "," as token. An example might be:

```
a < (b > c > (x, y, z))
```

From the above expression, I would deduct that:

1. a relies on b
2. b is a precondition of c
3. x, y and z depend on c independently
4. there is no relationship between a and c
5. there is no relationship between a, x, y and z

Is there any tool to support this kind of parsing?

thanks,
Green

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most famous tool for such things, I guess, is [ANTLR](http://antlr.org/).

Answer (score 2):

You can try JavaCC .. It is a bit tricky to get used to it but once you get it you can easily build such parsers.  You can start by following this [tutorial](http://www.engr.mun.ca/~theo/JavaCC-Tutorial/).  An [eclipse plugin](http://eclipse-javacc.sourceforge.net/) is also available which facilitates its use to generate the required files and so on.